# shear stress in hollow beam

Tags: structural-engineering

I m going to find the shear stress at section n-n . 
So , shear stress in beam has formula of τ = V(A)(y) / It, where y = distance from the centroid of particular area to neutral axis

I get the correct $I$ (second moment of inertia), but I'm having problem of finding the shear stress at $A$.

$V$ (shear force) is a constant 40 kN from 0 m to 0.4 m (in my SFD diagram).
For $A_y$, I have $100\times10^{-3}\cdot12\times10^{-3}\cdot(94-50)\times10^{-3} = 5.28\times10^{-5}\text{ mm}^4$

Is my Area (green coloured part) correct ?

so $\tau = \dfrac{40\times10^3\cdot5.28\times10^{-5}}{5553152 \cdot 12\times10^{-3}} = 3.81\times10^{-6}$, but the given ans is $15.85\times10^6$

Does the section n-n mean when we cut off the beam at n-n , the side view of n-n look like in the diagram?

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT: sorry , it should be τ = V(A)(y) / It , where y = distance from the centorid of particular area to neutral axis

---

EDIT: ***How  to  get  the 21.05 Mpa ?***  I only  get  the  15.8Mpa  after  correction.... $$\tau$$ = (40x10^3)(5.28x10^-5)/ [(5553152x10^-12)(24x10^-3)] = (15.8x10^6)MPa

Comment: the unit on ay you have calculated is meters cubed not millimeters^4. also i think t should be the total 24mm

Comment: the `I` in your book has the wrong unit, it must be `mm^4`

Comment: which part of my working is incorrect ? i didnt get the correct shear stress which is $$(15.85*10^6)$$

Comment: if you have corrected things you should *edit your question* to reflect the corrections.